# How can I detect that a file descriptor was redefined to a new filehandle?

Tags: multithreading, perl

In this code:

```perl
open my $fh1,'>','file1';
my $fh1_desc=fileno $fh1;
close $fh1;

open my $fh2,'>','file2';

open my $fh1_,'>&=',$fh1_desc;

if (fileno $fh1_ == fileno $fh2 ) {
    print "\$fh1_ and \$fh2 are dups\n";
}
```

After that `$fh1_` and `$fh2` point to the same file. How can I detect that the redefinition of file descriptor?

This is "dummy code"! The real case is: 
When I pass the file descriptor to a different thread how can I know that it wasn't redefined?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've closed a file handle, the numerical descriptor is meaningless, and will usually just be re-used by the next open, as you've shown.  My suggestion is that when you close a file, you make sure to set any handles you may have to 'undef' so you don't fool yourself into thinking they are still valid.

But I may have misunderstood your problem - you didn't supply very much detail.

Comment: from different threads we cannot have access to the filehandle itself.

Comment: I want to read new tcp connection in one thread and handle them in another one! I can pass the file descriptor but it can be redefined if some client closes his connection!

Comment: I think the problem you need to solve is how to notify the worker thread when a filehandle it is using has been closed.  I haven't done much multithreaded perl programming, but it looks to as if you could use the threads::shared module to share the filehandle between threads in order to solve this problem

Comment: Not so easy because filehandles cannot be shared with threads::shared!